# Looking for labeled audio data for sentiment

Tags: data-request, audio, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking for labelled audio data. Like a cat meowing, or a spoon falling on the ground, a car driving past, etc... i.e. sound clips of events. Does anyone know of where to find this? Would be very grateful for any help here.

Comment: What you describe is not sentiment (which is how positive or negative people feel or express themselves), but labels of  Sound Events.

Answer (score 3):

As with many new areas of research, this doesn't seem to be a domain with much truly open data, but you may be able to contact academic researchers about using datasets they have compiled for their work.

[This W3C wiki page on sentiment analysis](https://www.w3.org/community/sentiment/wiki/Datasets) lists several such datasets.

For example, the [Center for the Study of Emotion and Attention](http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/index.html) at University of Florida describes the [International Affective Digital Sound (IADS) system](http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/media.html):

> The International Affective Digitized Sound system (IADS) provides a
>   set of acoustic emotional stimuli for experimental investigations of
>   emotion and attention. This set of standardized,
>   emotionally-evocative, internationally accessible sound stimuli
>   includes contents across a wide range of semantic categories. The IADS
>   (pronounced "eye-ads") is being developed and distributed by the
>   Center for Emotion and Attention (CSEA) at the University of Florida.

See [their page](http://csea.phhp.ufl.edu/media.html) for details on requesting the data set.

This [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/wanghaohan/multimodal-sentiment-analysis) refers to several video datasets, but usable in analyzing the audio component. One of them is [MOSI: Multimodal Corpus of Sentiment Intensity and Subjectivity Analysis in Online Opinion Videos](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06259) I don't see an obvious channel for requesting that data, but you could reach out to the authors of the paper described at that link.